# Regular Expression, match ${ANY_TEXT}

Tags: regex

Can you please help me with reg ex. I cant make it :( I hate regex.
I need to match this string ${ANY_TEXT} .Exactly one "${" and exactly one closing tag "}".

Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: http://txt2re.com/index-csharp.php3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\$\{[^}]+\}` will match it. It will match `${ABC}` from `${ABC}}}` as well. If you want to match complete lines, simply anchor the regular expression using `^\$\{[^}]+\}$`.

A good site to learn regular expressions is http://www.regular-expressions.info/.

Comment: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in

I just need to match ${ABC} and then get the text between ${ and }

Comment: Im using that "$\{[^}]+\}$" to match agains {ANY_TEXT}. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this covers all the texts.

```
/^\$\{[a-zA-Z]\}$/
```

Comment: `[a-zA-z]` should be `[a-zA-Z]` (note the capital Z), and an explicit range of characters isn't a good choice in any event. As CappY points out, you have your final `$` outside the `/`, and it should be inside.

Comment: @DragoonWraith, Sleepy Eyes... always makes the most stupid of the mistakes. ;) (Thanks.. Corrected)